# Does tf.estimator.Estimator.evaluate() always run on one GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have the impression that calling `evaluate()` on a `tf.estimator.Estimator` instance does **not** run the model on multiple GPUs, even if the distribution strategy is `MirroredStrategy`, configured to use at least 2 GPUs.

Here is an exemplary script that suggests this behavior: https://gist.github.com/patzm/b69fcdf33fc9062683d749d0ea936b5e

Here is a screenshot of `nvidia-smi` showing this behavior:
[image: Exemplary screenshot of nvidia-smi]

If `evaluate()` should run, if used like above, on multiple GPUs, please highlight my mistakes in your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `RunConfig`, set the strategy to `eval_distribute` as well, detail see [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig)

```
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
    model_dir=tf.test.get_temp_dir(),
    session_config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True),
    train_distribute=distribution_strategy,
    eval_distribute=distribution_strategy
)
```